# MySQL multiple WHERE from same column?

Tags: mysql

User table

```
------------------------
id        |   name
------------------------
1         |  Bob Smith
2         |  Jane Doe
3         |  Fred Flintstone
4         |  Barney Rubble
5         |  Marge Simpson
...       |  ...
```

Connections

```
-----------------------------------------------
connection1 |   connection2  | connector
------------------------------------------------
1           |  3             | 7
11          |  5             | 7
35          |  7             | 7
18          |  9             | 7
12          |  13            | 6
...         |  ...           | ...
```

Above are examples of tables I have in a MySQL database. I understand I can use a WHERE clause to return a single user id but I would like to resolve all ids from the same user table. Is there any elegant solution to return just usernames in one MySQL statement?

Basically return a table like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------
connection1 |   connection2  | connector
------------------------------------------------
Tim         |  Steven        | Charlie
```

Comment: Yes, they're called joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do what you are trying to do, you need to join to the user table multiple times (one for each connection). Something like the following should do what you want to do.

```
SELECT
    t1.name as 'connection1',
    t2.name as 'connection2',
    t3.name as 'connection3'
FROM connections c
JOIN user t1 on t1.id = c.connection1
JOIN user t2 on t2.id = c.connection2
JOIN user t3 on t3.id = c.connection3
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL 101.  Use joins:

```
SELECT
    c1.name AS connection1_name,
    c2.name AS connection2_name,
    connector
FROM Connections cn
JOIN users c1 ON c1.Id = cn.connection1
JOIN users c2 ON c2.Id = cn.connection2
```